# Reducing Frequency of points in LineChartView?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

The line chart view below has too many data points and I'd like to reduce the frequency or smooth the line so that it's more readable, I can't find anything in the Charts documentation on this issue, is it possible?

[image]

Comment: What about modifying your data instead, I think it makes more sense to modify the data source.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that's a solution as well but how best to go about doing that? I really am not sure where to start

Comment: That's more a mathematical and/or statistical question that depends on the kind of data you have I presume, you could calculate a moving average or simply remove some of the data values